# Why doesn't my Pi camera work

Tags: camera

Here is my code:

```py
import time
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()

try:
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(10)
    camera.stop_preview()
finally:
    camera.close()
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/CamEx.py", line 4, in <module>
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

Comment: Did you enable the camera interface (run raspi-config)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if camera is enabled on raspi-config ? If not open raspi-config app or terminal:

```
sudo raspi-config
```